# MySQL query with count and row

Tags: mysql

I have a messages table and, I would like to know what would be the most efficient query to accomplish the following result:

Note thread field is null if the thread is the very first message all other messages are linked to that thread with is the emid

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
    `emid` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `emitter` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `receiver` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `thread` BIGINT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `opened` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT 0,
    `message` BLOB NOT NULL,
    `timecard` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `efk` FOREIGN KEY (`emitter`) REFERENCES `members` (`user_id`),
    ADD CONSTRAINT `rfk` FOREIGN KEY (`receiver`) REFERENCES `members` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I would like to get the first row for a given receiver including its messages count. Say for instance a user has 4 non opened messages (unread) and two replies. I would like to get the first message received under this thread and the total replies from both sides. At first I thought about sub queries but that seems like it will perform badly.

The following selects threads for user (receiver = id)

```
    SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE thread IS NULL AND receiver = 2 ORDER BY timecard DESC
```

This one get the message count under a given thread

```
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `messages` WHERE thread = 20
```

Comment: Getting the first message in the thread requires a subquery, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1. You can simply add `COUNT(*)` to the subquery that returns `MIN(timecard)` for each thread.

Comment: Please try to do that, and if you can't get it to work post your attempt. Then we can help you fix it. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: I can write no problem, and not asking to do it for me. My goal is to learn not to have done.

Comment: @Barmar There it is! What I would like is to know if there is a better way to accomplish that! Thread count and message count for each thread

Comment: What does that have to do with the question? Show how you try to join the queries to produce the result you want.

Comment: Neither of those queries looks like anything in the question I referred you to, to get the first message of each thread.

Comment: I guess because that does not resemble what I am looking for. It does work for me separately. I just wanna know if there is a way to do it more efficiently than with a sub query!

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought the first message was the lowest `timecard`.

Answer (score 1):

Join your two queries:

```
SELECT m1.*, IFNULL(COUNT(m2.emid), 0) AS replies
FROM messages AS m1
LEFT JOIN messages AS m2 ON m2.thread = m1.emid
WHERE m1.thread is NULL
GROUP BY m1.emid
```

The `WHERE` clause selects just the starting message from each thread from table `m1`.

`LEFT JOIN` then relates that to all the replies to that thread, using the `thread` column to link them back to the original message. I've used `LEFT JOIN` so that messages with no replies will be included.

`COUNT(m2.emid)` then counts the number of related rows, which is the number of replies in the thread. `COUNT()` only counts non-null values; if there are no replies, `LEFT JOIN` sets this column to `NULL`, so you'll get a count of `0`.

Comment: @RaymondNijland No it won't. All the other columns are functionally dependent on `emid`, since it's the primary key, so they don't need to be listed in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Assuming he's running 5.7.5 or newer, which is when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY became the default.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the query a little bit, as I mentioned before my goal is to learn!

Comment: @Barmar some MySQL versions didn't implement the GROUP BY on a PRIMARY KEY with sql_mode = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY correctly that's why i don't rely on it.

Comment: I mean to ask you if any of you could explain the full query!

Comment: I meant more explaining on the Aliasing I am pretty familiar with the very basics. The reason why I would like some explaining is because I at first glance I would think the query will go into an infinite loop. Also, seems to me like the aliasing prevents that from happening!

Comment: We're getting into some pretty basic SQL concepts here. SO is not a tutoring service, or a replacement for learning the language. The aliases allow you to refer to the same table twice, as if they were copies.

Comment: Is there a reason why removed your answer?

Comment: You mean in your other question? Because I misunderstood the question and the answer was wrong.